# Bundler "stalls" / "freezes" after installing a couple of gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I'm running

```
$ bundle install
```

in a directory with a Gemfile that contains only one gem:

```
$ cat Gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
```

[here is a pastebin from](http://pastebin.com/3rN6HezY) the `DEBUG_RESOLVER=y bundle install --verbose` output.

This process is run inside a docker container, during a `docker build` with this Dockerfile:

```
ENV RAILS_ENV staging
ENV HOME /rails_web_app/
ADD rails-app/Gemfile      Gemfile
ADD rails-app/Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
ENV DEBUG_RESOLVER true
RUN DEBUG_RESOLVER=true bundle install --verbose
```

After the first couple of gems are installed, the process just seems to sleep (At this point I've been waiting for 25 minutes and the last line from the pastebin is still being displayed). CPU usage is at 0%, network info tells me it is neither up nor downloading.

Versions:

- Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.5.0
- ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
- Bundler version 1.9.4

What I've tried so far:

- Restart boot2docker vm
- Reduce number of Gems (to only rails)
- Change the one gem to mysql2, *which works*

Further observations:

- It "sleeps" at different gems. (`builder 3.2.2`, `i18n 0.7.0`)